# N-Queens, Java using LinkedList Stack

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, n-queens

Working on the N-queens problem. Having some difficult filling up the stack correctly. Was hoping anyone could give me any pointers.

Right now my output is strange..There are only 7 nodes, but my 'success' boolean needs 8 for it to be true. And the head node is 2,1 when I thought it should be 1,2 since I'd be increasing the column.

I know I need to check for the diagonal also, but I'm taking it step by step.

The first thing I need to work out if my conflictCheck method. It never return true (for, yes there is a conflict). I'll update shortly if I figure something out.

```
Hurray
8, 1
7, 1
6, 1
5, 1
4, 1
3, 1
2, 1
```

EDIT:

I've made some changes to the code for a more recursive attempt.
My new output is this:

```
The stack
1, 1

End of stack
Pushing next node
The stack
2, 1
1, 1

End of stack
Moving over one column
The stack
2, 2
1, 1

End of stack
problem
Moving over one column
The stack
2, 3
1, 1

End of stack
```

This is part of the code/work in progress. Right now, it's running into an eternal loop, most likely from that while (conflictCheck)

```
    public static boolean conflictCheck() {
    QueenNode temp = head;
    //walk through stack and check for conflicts

    while(temp!=null) {
        //if there is no next node, there is no conflict with it
        if (temp.getNext() == null){
            System.out.println("No next node");
            if (queens.size() < 8 ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (temp.getRow() ==temp.getNext().getRow() || temp.getColumn() == temp.getNext().getColumn() ||
                diagonal(temp, temp.getNext())){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void mover(QueenNode n) {
    System.out.println("Moving over one column");

        n.setColumn(n.getColumn()+1);

    queens.viewPieces();
}

public static void playChess(int k, int total) {
    QueenNode temp= head;
    while (temp != null) {
        System.out.println("Pushing next node");

        queens.push(k,1);
        queens.viewPieces();
        //success
        if(k == 8){
            System.out.println("Hurray");
            success = true;
            return;
        }
        //conflict between pieces, loops through entire board
        while (conflictCheck()) {
            if (head.getColumn() != 8) {
                mover(head);
            }
            else {
                queens.pop();
                mover(head);
            }
        }

        playChess(k+1, total);                  
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    queens.push(1, 1);
    queens.viewPieces();
    success = false;
    playChess(2, total);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp != null && temp.getNext()!= null` - for 8th queen the value temp.getNext() is null and it is not printed. Change to:

```
while (temp != null ) {
                System.out.println(temp.getRow() + ", " + temp.getColumn());
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
```

---

**Edit**

Change || to &&:

```
if (temp.getRow() != temp.getNext().getRow() &&
                temp.getColumn() != temp.getNext().getColumn()) {
            return false;
        }
```

In code  `queens.push(queens.size()+1, 1);` you always assign 1 as second argument. You should check all possibilities.

Comment: I made some edits, I'm trying to figure out how to deal with conflicts. If there's a conflict and the top's column is 8, you want to pop it off and move the next top's column up by 1. If the column isn't 8, just move the top's column up by 1 and recheck for conflicts. Right now, I have an eternal loop :/